# 'top -p PID -n1' not working as cronjob

Tags: cron

With totem playing a video, running `top -p $(pidof totem) -n1` from the terminal works perfectly.  Extending it slightly to `top -p $(pidof totem) -n1 > ~/test.txt` and running it as a once-per-minute cronjob, `test.txt` is written to, but produces a blank document. There are no errors being produced, or at least nothing is listed in the log files, and Cron doesn't send any mail alerts indicating a problem either. I have no problem getting Cron to run other scripts.

The same thing occurs with all 3 Linux distros I have - Mint 17.2, Deepin 2014, and Ubuntu 10.04.

I have found posts from several people who have encountered the same problem, but unfortunately none of the below suggestions they received work for me;

adding the following;

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

or any of the following;

```
export TERM=xterm
top -bn1 | head
TERM=dumb top -n1 | head
TERM=xterm top -n1 | head
```

At this stage, I'm beginning to think that it's top itself that's buggy. After spending many hours working on a Bash script that's based around `top -p`, it's pretty demoralising to discover that once done, I now can't get it to run as a cronjob.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to what the problem might be?

Edit:  I'm a mite embarrassed to admit that `top -p PID -bn1 | head` does work after all!  I must have mistyped or something when I tried it first time around!  Nevermind, hope it's of help to someone in the future.

Comment: Note that you might have better luck on serverfault, as this is a stretch to call programming related.

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to the title. If your problem is solved post an answer.

Comment: I did - it's included in the "Edit:" addition.  Anyone with a similar problem will read the entire post and come to the 'Edit:' bit.